# How to clear cookies using angularJs while logout

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have some angular login and logout controller as given bellow

**Login Controller**

```
$scope.login = function (username, password) {
       UserService.login({
         'username': username,
         'password': password
       }, function (data) {
          console.log("loggggg ", data);
          AuthFactory.refresh();
                if ($scope.currentUser.isSuperAdmin()) {
                    console.log("insideSuperAdmin");
                    $state.go("main.landing ", {reload: true});
                } else if ($scope.currentUser.isAdminADC()) {
                    console.log("inside admin adc");
                    $state.go("main.landing ", {reload: true});
                } else if ($scope.currentUser.isAdminMOM()) {
                    console.log("inside mom admin");
                    $state.go("main.meeting_manager ", {reload: true});
                }
            }, function () {
                $scope.error = "Login Failed. Invalid Credentials.";
            });
        };
```

I am getting currentUser from my authentication.js

**Logout Controller**

```
$scope.logout = function () {
     UserService.logout({}, function () {
          $state.go("login", {
             'message': 'Logged Out Successfully!'
          });
     });
 };
```

I want to use role based security on logging as above.
but at the time of logout I want to clear cookies.
**My Problem** is when I clear browser cookies manually then it run properly on chrome but when I did not clear cookies manually that time logging user role perform on its previously logged in user.
so I want to clear cookies

Comment: UserService.logout has to clear the cookies

Comment: how to clear userservice

Comment: What cookie service are you using for angular? Most have their own method of removing cookies.

Comment: I am guessing UserService is a resource and you are loggin in with some backend server? The back end server is the one to delete the cookie once you logout. All you have to do from the front is delete whatever data you are saving after login (maybe the logged user data or whatever)

Comment: @user1655756 yes I am getting what you want to say, but new in it, so I am not getting how to remove. so please share your answer so I can apply it

Comment: What are you using in your backend? passport?